# error "invalid use of undefined type 'struct cmplx' dereferencing pointer to incomplete type". How to fix it?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C programming and i have a code which somebody else has written and i just need to make it working or compile it.

```
 # include <stdio.h>
 # include <math.h>

 # define AP_INC        1
 # define H_INC     4

/* plot the power spectrum */
do_peak(ftdat,n_out,recno)
struct cmplx *ftdat;
int n_out;
int recno;
{
extern float del_f;
extern float del_t;
extern FILE *pkfile;
extern int ilowpk;
extern int ihipk;
float time;
float fpeak;
float pkval;
int ipeak;
int i;

/* find the peak of the spectrum */
pkval = ftdat[ilowpk];
ipeak = ilowpk;

if(ilowpk < ihipk){
    for(i = ilowpk+1; i < ihipk; i++){
        if(ftdat[i] > pkval){
            pkval = ftdat[i];
            ipeak = i;
        }
    }
} else {
    for(i = ilowpk+1; i < n_out; i++){
        if(ftdat[i] > pkval){
            pkval = ftdat[i];
            ipeak = i;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < ihipk; i++){
        if(ftdat[i] > pkval){
            pkval = ftdat[i];
            ipeak = i;
        }
    }
}

/* convert ipeak to a frequency */
fpeak = (float)ipeak*del_f;

/* compute the time */
time = (float) recno*del_t;

/* write to output file */
fprintf(pkfile,"%f %g\n",time,fpeak);
return;
}
```

The error i get is "invalid use of undefined type 'struct cmplx'  dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"
You all can check this link for more info http://codepad.org/HdbgppgM
Please do let me know how to fix it. 
Keep in mind that i have no knowledge of C but only matlab. 
Thank you 
Anil.

Comment: some consistent style please. Also, that code is far from minimal...

Comment: Also, consider writing C with prototypes instead of pre-ANSI-C.

Comment: This is what i got when i used codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

pkval = ftdat[ilowpk]; <- here, you are treating ftdat as a pointer to an array of **struct cmplx** (similar to char * usually being an array of chars), extracting one **struct cmplx** at position ilowpk and assigning it to pkval.

You can't extract the struct from the array because all the compiler has is a forward declaration - it does not know how big the struct is. Because of that it doesn't even know where to look relating to the beginning of the array.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: You have to provide an implementation of struct cmplx. It's probably in some header file somewhere. You will have to `include "cmplx.h"` or something similar.

Comment: Adding include 'cmplx.h" did not fix it yet.